# Should I add descriptions of courses taught on my CV

Tags: cv

I'm working on my CV right now. I have been teaching EFL at a university for 2 years. It has been my first university position. I am planning on applying at universities back in the States soon. I am educationally-qualified (meaning, I have the degrees required), however I do not have much experience (6 years teaching, only 2 university). I wanted to list as much information as possible, so I have been writing about each course I have taught (about 6 different courses). I have included course name, objective, textbook, and course highlights (meaning unique projects that would set my courses apart). I am wondering if this is necessary or useful?

Comment: EFL = English as a Foreign Language? Is that the term being used instead of ESL now?

Comment: @HuckBennett EFL is used for people learning English in a non-English-speaking country. ESL is used for people learning English in an English-speaking country.

Comment: @HuckBennett ESL=English as a Second Language. The way I understand it is that EFL and ESL have been mixed usage. See [this Wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_as_a_second_or_foreign_language)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A brief description of the courses you've taught is never remiss, as it helps reviewers place your teaching work into context. This is especially important for teaching-primary positions. However, for many positions, you also have the ability (or requirement) to submit a "teaching statement." This would be a place, for instance, where you could discuss your unique projects.

What I would certainly want people to know about in the courses I taught:

- Full course name
- Whether they were required or elective
- The intended audience (e.g., "freshmen" or "upper-year undergraduates and graduates in the major")
- How long (how many times) you taught the course
- Did you have sole responsibility, or was it co-taught
- Format of the class (lecture, seminar, laboratory, etc.)
- A brief description of the course, if its nature cannot be inferred from the title (for example, "Introduction to US History to 1865" doesn't need an explanation; "The Critical Period" would.)

Other information could be listed on a "courses taught" appendix, but I might not necessarily include it directly in the CV.

Comment: Do you think it would be better to list the courses and their descriptions right under the university position, or as an appendix?

Comment: Personally, I list them under a separate section of my CV. Basically, the more courses you have, the more important it is to separate it out (in the interests of clarity, organization, and readability.)